# Anchor tag isn't aligning to left edge of div element

Tags: css

I'm struggling to figure out why the anchor tag for this icon isn't aligning to the left edge of the div. Is it the specific character () that's causing it? The anchor's size is larger than the 29x29px space of the div element, but I'm not sure why that is happening either. The page can be found at https://www.oakmotorsdev.com/inventory/

[image]

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question, rather than asking people to dig through your site to figure out how to trigger the popup you're asking about.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in the question itself. It will help us now by providing us an example of the issue without irrelevant code. It will help visitors in the future when you site changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the width of the icon is 37px but the width of its container (the div with class refresh) is 29px; you can set the width of the div to 39px to achieve what you want.

You can see the result [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OI15V.jpg)

Comment: I've made the adjustment. I'm not sure why the anchor is 37px to begin with since the icon doesn't look like it should have that width. There's no margin or padding but it has whitespace around it.